# Utilizar metodos seters dentro de uma função void

Tags: java, android

Eu sou meio novato em java e estou tentando criar uma aplicação em que chamo dados do servidor e preencho um objeto, mas o objeto não é preenchido, sempre que eu chamo o objeto todos os atributos são nulos.

A função para chamada de dados do servidor é essa:

```
public void preencherObj(Context context, final Aplicativo aplicativo){
    try{
        Ion.with(context)
            .load(Constantes.url)
            .setBodyParameter("id_empresa", String.valueOf(Constantes.id_empresa))
            .setBodyParameter("acao", "B")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    aplicativo.setId_aplicativo(result.get("id_aplicativo").getAsInt());
                    aplicativo.setNm_cor(result.get("nm_cor").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNr_telefone(result.get("nr_telefone").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNr_telefone2(result.get("nr_telefone2").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_logo(result.get("url_logo").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_whats(result.get("url_whats").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_local(result.get("url_local").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_site(result.get("url_site").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_endereco(result.get("nm_endereco").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_cidade(result.get("nm_cidade").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_estado(result.get("nm_estado").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setCd_cep(result.get("cd_cep").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_app(result.get("url_app").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_empresa(result.get("nm_empresa").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_logo_splash(result.get("url_logo_splash").getAsString());
                }
            });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Metodos.ShowPopup(context);
    }
}
```

Alguém saberia me dizer por que o objeto sempre retorna nulo depois da chamada da função?

Comment: Tenta tirar aquela palavra reservada `final` na definição do método e testa de novo

Comment: Será que você está tentando resgatar os atributos antes de `.setCallback()` seta-los? pois `.setCallback()` é assíncrono.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando seu código, os valores do atributo `aplicativo` só estará disponível dentro da própria `public void`. Eu faria o seguinte para utilizar os valores retornados do JSON para fora da função:

```
//Início
Aplicativo dadosApp;
//...
//Sua função
public void preencherObj(Context context, final Aplicativo aplicativo){
    try{
        Ion.with(context)
            .load(Constantes.url)
            .setBodyParameter("id_empresa", String.valueOf(Constantes.id_empresa))
            .setBodyParameter("acao", "B")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    aplicativo.setId_aplicativo(result.get("id_aplicativo").getAsInt());
                    aplicativo.setNm_cor(result.get("nm_cor").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNr_telefone(result.get("nr_telefone").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNr_telefone2(result.get("nr_telefone2").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_logo(result.get("url_logo").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_whats(result.get("url_whats").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_local(result.get("url_local").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_site(result.get("url_site").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_endereco(result.get("nm_endereco").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_cidade(result.get("nm_cidade").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_estado(result.get("nm_estado").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setCd_cep(result.get("cd_cep").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_app(result.get("url_app").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_empresa(result.get("nm_empresa").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_logo_splash(result.get("url_logo_splash").getAsString());
                }
            });
            dadosApp = aplicativo;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Metodos.ShowPopup(context);
    }
}
```

Utilizando dessa maneira a variável `dadosApp` terá toda a informação que você tem na variável interna aplicativo, ou se preferir pode usar da seguinte maneira:

```
//Início
Aplicativo aplicativo;
//...
//Sua função
public void preencherObj(Context context){
    try{
        Ion.with(context)
            .load(Constantes.url)
            .setBodyParameter("id_empresa", String.valueOf(Constantes.id_empresa))
            .setBodyParameter("acao", "B")
            .asJsonObject()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonObject result) {
                    aplicativo.setId_aplicativo(result.get("id_aplicativo").getAsInt());
                    aplicativo.setNm_cor(result.get("nm_cor").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNr_telefone(result.get("nr_telefone").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNr_telefone2(result.get("nr_telefone2").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_logo(result.get("url_logo").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_whats(result.get("url_whats").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_local(result.get("url_local").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_site(result.get("url_site").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_endereco(result.get("nm_endereco").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_cidade(result.get("nm_cidade").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_estado(result.get("nm_estado").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setCd_cep(result.get("cd_cep").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_app(result.get("url_app").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setNm_empresa(result.get("nm_empresa").getAsString());
                    aplicativo.setUrl_logo_splash(result.get("url_logo_splash").getAsString());
                }
            });
    }catch (Exception e){
        Metodos.ShowPopup(context);
    }
}
```

Assim você garante que qualquer outra função que for utilizar a variável `aplicativo` encontrará as informações, pois elas estarão na variável global e não mais na variável local da função `preencherObj`.